# Python, how to merge 2 pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, merge, dataframe

Lets say I have two differents pandas Dataframe with different index
for example:

df1:

```
email                |       other_field
_________________________________________
email1@email.com     |           2
email2@email.com     |           1
email3@email.com     |           6
```

and df2:

```
new_field
__________
    1
    7
    4
```

The 2 dataframes have the same size.
How can I merge the two of them to have this similar output?

df3:

```
email                |       other_field     |       new_field
________________________________________________________________
email1@email.com     |           2           |           1
email2@email.com     |           1           |           7
email3@email.com     |           6           |           4
```

I tried this:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

but despite df1 and df2 has the same size, df3 has a lower size

Comment: If the lengths are the same you can just concat `pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1, ignore_index=True)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just `concat` in this case:

```
In [70]:

pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)

Out[70]:
              email  other_field  new_field
0  email1@email.com            2          1
1  email2@email.com            1          7
2  email3@email.com            6          4
```

You could elect to pass `ignore_index=True` if required.

`join` would also work:

```
In [71]:

df1.join(df2)

Out[71]:
              email  other_field  new_field
0  email1@email.com            2          1
1  email2@email.com            1          7
2  email3@email.com            6          4
```

Also in the case where the indices match, direct assignment would also work:

```
In [72]:

df1['new_field'] = df2['new_field']
df1
Out[72]:
              email  other_field  new_field
0  email1@email.com            2          1
1  email2@email.com            1          7
2  email3@email.com            6          4
```